# Pandas: replace values in strings

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have data frame and I try to replace it from other df

I use:

```
df['term_code'] = df.search_term.map(rep_term.set_index('search_term')['code_action'])
```

But I get an error:

```
File "C:/Users/����� �����������/Desktop/projects/find_time_before_buy/graph (2).py", line 36, in <module>
df['term_code'] = df.search_term.map(rep_term.set_index('search_term')['code_action'])
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 2101, in map
indexer = arg.index.get_indexer(values)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2082, in get_indexer
   raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
pandas.indexes.base.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

What should I change?
Where `search_term` is

```
729948                               None  
729949                               None  
729950                               None  
729951  пансионат джемете отдых 2016 цены  
729952                               None  
729953                               None  
729954                               купить телефон  
729955                               None  
729956                               вк  
729957                               None  
729958                               яндекс
```

And `rep_term` looks like

```
search_term code_action
авито   6
вк  9
яндекс  12
мтс 7
связной 8
ситилинк    8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is problem with duplicates in `DataFrame` `rep_term` column `search_term`.

I simulate it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'search_term':[1,2,3]})

print (df)
   search_term
0            1
1            2
2            3
```

For value `1` in `search_term` you have `2` values in `code_action`:

```
rep_term = pd.DataFrame({'search_term':[1,2,1], 'code_action':['ss','dd','gg']})
print (rep_term)
  code_action  search_term
0          ss            1
1          dd            2
2          gg            1


df['term_code'] = df.search_term.map(rep_term.set_index('search_term')['code_action'])
print (df)
#InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

So first identify rows where are duplicated vaues by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
print (rep_term[rep_term.duplicated(subset=['search_term'], keep=False)])
  code_action  search_term
0          ss            1
2          gg            1
```

Then you can drop duplicity with keeping last or first values by [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

```
rep_term1 = rep_term.drop_duplicates(subset=['search_term'], keep='first')
print (rep_term1)
  code_action  search_term
0          ss            1
1          dd            2

rep_term2 = rep_term.drop_duplicates(subset=['search_term'], keep='last')
print (rep_term2)
  code_action  search_term
1          dd            2
2          gg            1
```

Comment: Should I rename column? When name of this column was another, it returned this error too.

Comment: Give me a sec,  I add what can you do to answer.